# Get matrix for an X gate for a given fidelity p

Tags: quantum-operation, kraus-representation

Wanted to check on how to mathematically obtain the matrix of an X gate which has fidelity/probability $p$? (i.e. it acts as an $X$ gate with probability $p$)

Comment: And what does the gate act as with probability $1-p$?

Comment: It acts as I gate

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to represent this isn't via a matrix, but via the Kraus representation. That is, a quantum operation can be written as:
$$\rho\mapsto\sum_iK_i\rho K_i^\dagger$$
with $\sum\limits_iK_i^\dagger K_i\leqslant I$. Here, the quantum operation you're looking for is the well-known bit-flip channel with probability $p$:
$$\rho\mapsto(1-p)\rho+pX\rho X$$
That is, with probability $1-p$, nothing is done on the quantum state, and with probability $p$ an $X$ gate is applied. Here, the Kraus operators describing this operation are $K_0=\sqrt{1-p}I$ and $K_1=\sqrt{p}X$.

Comment: I was interpreting OP's question as $X$ gate occurs with probability $p$ and erroneous $X$ gate occurs with probability $1-p$, like $e^{-i \theta X}$ with $\theta \neq \frac{\pi}{2}$.